# child waiting for another child

Tags: c++, c, fork

is there a way for a forked child to examine another forked child so that, if the other forked child takes more time than usual to perform its chores, the first child may perform predefined steps?
if so, sample code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Simply fork the process to be watched, *from the process to watch it*.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    // we are the watcher
    pid_t watchee_pid = fork();
    if (watchee_pid != 0) {
        // wait and/or handle timeout
        int status;
        waitpid(watchee_pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    } else {
        // we're being watched. do stuff
    }
} else {
    // original process
}
```

To emphasise: There are 3 processes. The original, the watcher process (that handles timeout etc.) and the actual watched process.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to use some form of IPC, and named shared memory segments makes perfect sense here. Your first child could read a value in a named segment which the other child will set once it has completed it's work. Your first child could set a time out and once that time out expires, check for the value - if the value is not set, then do what you need to do.

The code can vary greatly depending on C or C++, you need to select which. If C++, you can use `boost::interprocess` for this - which has lots of examples of shared memory usage. If C, then you'll have to put this together using native calls for your OS - again this should be fairly straightforward - start at `shmget()`

Answer (score 0):

This is some orientative code that could help you to solve the problem in a Linux environment.

```
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1) {
    printf("fork: %s", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    /* parent process */
    int i = 0;
    int secs = 60; /* 60 secs for the process to finish */
    while(1) {
        /* check if process with pid exists */
        if (exist(pid) && i > secs) {
          /* do something accordingly */
        }
        sleep(1);
        i++;
    }
  } else {
    /* child process */
    /* child logic here */
    exit(0);
  }
```

... those 60 seconds are not very strict. you could better use a timer if you want more strict timing measurement. But if your system doesn't need critical real time processing should be just fine like this.

`exist(pid)` refers to a function that you should have code that looks into `proc/pid` where `pid` is the process id of the child process.

Optionally, you can implement the function `exist(pid)` using other libraries designed to extract information from the `/proc` directory like [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Where is one child examining other? it looks like parent doing something.

Comment: Yes I was finishing the answer. Look at the new edition where it says `exist(pid)`

Comment: To check for process existance, use kill(pid, 0). The 0 signal won't do anything but the kill system call will return success or failure.

Comment: Checking for existence this way has race conditions unless you know (1) the parent has not yet waited on that pid, and (2) the parent itself has not somehow terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The only processes you can `wait` on are your own direct child processes - not siblings, not your parent, not grandchildren, etc. Depending on your program's needs, Matt's solution *may* work for you. If not, here are some other alternatives:

- Forget about waiting and use another form of IPC. For robustness, it needs to be something where unexpected termination of the process you're waiting on results in your receiving an event. The best one I can think of is opening a `pipe` which both processes share, and giving the writing end of the pipe to the process you want to wait for (make sure no other processes keep the writing end open!). When the process holding the writing end terminates, it will be closed, and the reading end will then indicate `EOF` (`read` will block on it until the writing end is closed, then return a zero-length read).
- Forget about IPC and use threads. One advantage of threads is that the atomicity of a "process" is preserved. It's impossible for individual threads to be killed or otherwise terminate outside of the control of your program, so you don't have to worry about race conditions with process ids and shared resource allocation in the system-global namespace (IPC objects, filenames, sockets, etc.). All synchronization primitives exist purely within your process's address space.

Comment: One nice aspect of the pipe/write trick is that it works *even if the child to be watched is a separate program*, as long as that program doesn't actively try to close unwanted file descriptors it inherited from its parent.